# Как обрабатываются скобки в обратной польской нотации?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Пытаюсь реализовать обратную польскую запись. Со знаками +, -, /, * работает верно. Но не работает если в обрабатываемую строку добавить скобки. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста.

Код для обработки знаков работает по такому алгоритму:

1. Если встречается операнд, то он помещается в выходную строку
2. Если алгоритм встречает оператор:

2.1. Стек пуст - оператор помещается в стек

2.2. Если входящий оператор имеет более высокий приоритет, чем тот оператор, что в настоящее время находится на вершине стека, входящий оператор помещается на вершину стека

2.3. Если входящий оператор имеет такой же приоритет, верхний оператор извлекается из стека и выводится в очередь, а входящий оператор помещается в стек

2.4. Если приоритет входящего оператора ниже, верхний оператор извлекается из стека и выводится в очередь, после чего входящий оператор сравнивается с новой вершиной стека

3. Когда вся строка проанализирована операторы переносятся в выходную строку

Для обработки скобок я решил дополнить алгоритм:

1. Если встретили '(' - помещаем её в стек.
2. Если встретили ')', - извлекаем символы из стека в выходную строку пока не встретится '('.

```
bool is_number(char ch)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        result = true;
    return result;
}

int prioritet(char ch)
{
    int prioritet;
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 4;
    case '-':
    case '+':
        return 3;
    case '(':
        return 2;
    case ')':
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

string Reverse_Polish_Natation(string input_string)
{
    char ch;
    string output_string;
    stack<char> stek_operator;

    for (int i = 0; i < input_string.size(); ++i)
    {
        ch = input_string[i];

        if (is_number(ch) == true)
        {
            while (is_number(ch) == true)
            {
                output_string.push_back(ch);
                i++;
                ch = input_string[i];
            }
            output_string.push_back(' ');
        }
        else if (ch == ' ')
        {
            while (input_string[i] == ' ')
                i++;
            i--;
        }
        else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (stek_operator.empty() || prioritet(ch) > prioritet(stek_operator.top()) || prioritet(ch) == 2)
                {
                    stek_operator.push(ch);
                    break;
                }
                if (prioritet(ch) == 1)
                {
                    while (prioritet(stek_operator.top()) == 2)
                    {
                        output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                        stek_operator.pop();
                    }
                }

                if (prioritet(ch) == prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                    output_string.push_back(' ');
                    stek_operator.pop();
                    stek_operator.push(ch);
                    break;
                }
                if (prioritet(ch) < prioritet(stek_operator.top()))
                {
                    output_string.push_back(stek_operator.top());
                    output_string.push_back(' ');
                    stek_operator.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (!stek_operator.empty())
    {
        ch = stek_operator.top();
        stek_operator.pop();
        output_string.push_back(ch);
        output_string.push_back(' ');
    }
    cout << output_string << endl;
    return output_string;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "(2 + 3) * 4";
    Reverse_Polish_Natation(s);
}
```

Comment: В обратной польской нотации скобки не используются, как и приоритет у операторов.

Comment: А тут похоже реализация перевода в обратную польскую запись и реализация алгоритма Дейкстры - сортировочная станция

Comment: Здесь выражение в строке преобразуется в обратную польскую запись. Но я не могу найти ошибку в программе. То есть когда во входном выражении нет скобок, программа правильно осуществляет перевод в ОПЗ, но когда добавляю скобки во входное выражение - преобразование происходит не верно. И я не могу обнаружить ошибку в коде

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример который не работает и опишите как должно быть и как есть сейчас.